# How to call an Extbase CommandController via Webhook URL

Tags: typo3, scheduler, webhooks, extbase

I would like to call an Extbase CommandController via an URL. The aim is to call it from outside to start an Import.

Yes it would be perfectly possible with SSH but the Software provides Webhook-URLs - so is this possible - if yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the logic of your command controller to a service and then call this service both from your command controller and from a [PSR-15 middleware](https://usetypo3.com/psr15-middleware-in-typo3.html) (TYPO3v9+) or an eID script.

Comment: Mh currently on TYPO3 v8 on this project... will have a look at this eID thing.